# USB WLAN problem after upgrading to 15.10

Tags: networking, upgrade, usb, xubuntu

After upgrading to XUbuntu 15.10 x64, the Wifi-USB stopped working reliably.

Prior to this, it worked out of the box.

Nowadays, what helps is

```
sudo killall -9 dhclient
sudo dhclient enxd66bf35ea5e5
```

(The interface was renamed from `usb0` to `enxd66bf35ea5e5` after the upgrade).

**How do you get NetworkManager to connect by default again?**

Here is the *dmesg*

```
[26458.123257] usb 3-1.2: Product: Nexus 7
[26458.123261] usb 3-1.2: Manufacturer: asus
[26458.123266] usb 3-1.2: SerialNumber: 08e6f5b1
[26465.043246] usb 3-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 7
[26465.243594] usb 3-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[26465.337324] usb 3-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=4ee3
[26465.337336] usb 3-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[26465.337342] usb 3-1.2: Product: Nexus 7
[26465.337348] usb 3-1.2: Manufacturer: asus
[26465.337353] usb 3-1.2: SerialNumber: 08e6f5b1
[26465.340533] rndis_host 3-1.2:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2, RNDIS device, d6:6b:f3:5e:a5:e5
[26465.549225] rndis_host 3-1.2:1.0 enxd66bf35ea5e5: renamed from usb0
[26465.591126] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enxd66bf35ea5e5: link is not ready
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to **add the user to the `netdev` group**. This seems to be now needed for NetworkManager to reconnect. (Previously, it was only needed to edit f.ex. wifi settings)

Most direct way:

```
sudo nano /etc/group
```

append username to `netdev` line.

Command line utility:

```
sudo usermod -G netdev -a username
```